# Cant update table from text using linq2sql

Tags: c#, winforms, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

Using linq2sql I'm trying to take the string in `txtOilChange` and update the `oilChange` integer in the `car` table of the white fusion.

I know my code below is wrong but what do I need to change?

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
var o = (from c in db.cars
where c.carDesc == "White Fusion"
select c).First();

txtOilChange.Text = o.oilChange.ToString();

db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: can you format your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to update the record it looks like the assignment statement is reversed.

This:

```
txtOilChange.Text = o.oilChange.ToString();
```

Should be:

```
o.oilChange = int.Parse(txtOilChange.Text);
```

For better error handling consider using the [`TryParse` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx):

```
int oilChangeValue;
if (int.TryParse(txtOilChange.Text, out oilChangeValue))
{
    o.oilChange = oilChangeValue;
    db.SubmitChanges();
} 
else
{
    // invalid value
}
```